# Android JNI - undefined reference while linking a static library

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Im trying to add a static library to an android application (with JNI support). My problem is that when I'm trying to build project, I receive an linker error (undefined reference). Linker is unable to header files with methods defined in this .a,

Build ends with:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildArm7Debug'.

  > Build command failed.
  >   Error while executing process /home/konrad/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/konrad/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloJNI/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/arm7Debug/armeabi-v7a --target hello-jni}
  >   [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/hello-jni.dir/hello-jni.c.o
  >   [2/2] Linking C shared library /home/konrad/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloJNI/app/build/intermediates/cmake/arm7/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so
  >   FAILED: : && /home/konrad/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/konrad/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/konrad/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-23/arch-arm -fPIC -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libhello-jni.so -o /home/konrad/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloJNI/app/build/intermediates/cmake/arm7/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so CMakeFiles/hello-jni.dir/hello-jni.c.o  /home/konrad/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloJNI/app/src/main/prebuild/lib/testlib.a -landroid -llog -lm && :
  >   /home/konrad/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloJNI/app/src/main/cpp/hello-jni.c:71: error: undefined reference to 'getBuff'
  >   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  >   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Could someone send me any clues what im missing?

My CMAKELists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

    ADD_LIBRARY(testlib STATIC IMPORTED)
    add_library(hello-jni SHARED
                hello-jni.c)

    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(testlib PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION path/to/testlib.a)


    include_directories(
                        /path/to/testlib/include
                        )

    # Include libraries needed for hello-jni lib
    target_link_libraries(hello-jni testlib
                          android
                          log)
```

Best regards,

Comment: I have all mandatory includes:

#include <jni.h>
#include "testlib.h"

...

struct bitmapType* bm = getBuff();

Build finished without any problem. But linker is unable to find header.

Comment: linker says `getBuff` is undefined, in what library it is implemented? in `testlib`? if so post the sources of `testlib`

Comment: Method is inside testlib.a. Its a static library build on basis of Cyanogemmod sources. This lib is not build as a part of this project. Im just trying to use its methods inside android using JNI. Its build for armeabi-v7a so it should work.

Comment: whats the output of `nm /home/konrad/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloJNI/app/src/main/prebuild/lib/testlib.a | grep getBuff`?

Comment: Yes:

konrad@KB:~/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloJNI/app/src/main/prebuild/lib$ nm ./testlib.a | grep get
0000000000000000 T _Z24getBuffv

So theoretically it is there.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extern-c-in-c/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still is a problem. Compilation of cpp code itself passed, but the same header is causing a problems in adroid studio:   
  In file included from /home/konrad/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloJNI/app/src/main/cpp/hello-jni.c:19:
  /home/konrad/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloJNI/app/src/main/cpp/testlib.h:5:8: error: expected identifier or '('
  extern "C" {
         ^

Comment: This header is very simple. struct retBuff {
    const void* buff;
    double buff_size;
};
extern "C" {
 struct retBuff* getBuff( );
}

Comment: hmm try `#ifdef __cplusplus<crlf>
extern "C" {<crlf>
#endif`<crlf> (its 3 lines, see zlib.h in ndk folder for exampl)

Comment: Master - u ar genius!!! Thanks!!!!

Comment: yea i know it ;-) tell it to my employer...